# Deploy project on Gitlab.com to Local Minikube

Tags: docker, deployment, gitlab, gitlab-ci, minikube

I'm playing with Gitlab and trying to build a basic pipeline for a microservices project in java and spring boot. Each microservice has its own repo in gitlab.com, they are public. I managed to complete the steps:

1. build -> mvn compile
2. test -> mvn verify with Sonar integration
3. release -> mvn release on gitlab package registry using local gitlab-runner
4. docker -> pushed docker image using a dockerfile to the gitlab container registry
5. deploy on minikube that runs locally on a docker container.

There's a guide to run gitlab on minikube but I don't want to do that as it adds a level of complexity I don't want to have.
All I want is to copy that docker image and deploying it on my local minikube.. Is it possible or do I need to have a public kubernetes via free gmail GCP ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need, you can do that with minikube.
just take note external ip is the minikube ip and it is the ip that will be used. scaling node might be more complex down the road as u will need to reconfigure add/remove them down the road or hardcore.

Also, i am not very fond of the crud of memory used for for my local machine hardware when the files are large(and possibly highly repetitive). i always felt it adds additional stress that can be offloaded to something(cloud) else.

AND YES, if you have the budget(or still the credits), i will highly recommend GCP over minikube for the value it brings... minikube is good for many things, but does not really give a real world feel. POC is great, i love minikube for quick tests.

Comment: Thanks. I will use gcp at some point but want to start with minikube as it's free and good to experiment

Comment: do you know any sources where I can learn how to deploy !?

Comment: for step 5 and loop? id call upon jenkins to help with this process. just create the job on jenkins, should be quite ok. remember to look at minikube ip